# Errors with iTunes Connect and Bundle IDs

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

So I created my app record in iTunes connect, and set the bundle id to `com.mycompany.ios.appname` Then, when I went back to my Xcode project I get the error:

[image: error]

This is my config:

[image: config]

I was added to another dev team if that makes any difference, and I created a new apple id from the link sent to my email.

I have no idea what I'm doing, and I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error shows that you have not created a provisioning profile under your apple account team.

Create appId with same bundle identifier then create provisioning profile with your appId. Download your provisioning profile and install it in your System.

Hope it would help you.

Comment: @Minebomber, when you will download your provisioning profile, it will automatically save in your downloads folder. Double click on it and it will automatically show in your system. You can check with iPhone Configuration Utility.

Comment: @Minebomber, Download your provisioning profile from apple developer account: Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> Provisioning Profiles

Answer (score 0):

uncheck automatically manage signing.

Double click on the provisioning profile ypu downloaded.

check on automatically manage signing.

Select team.

Comment: From apple developer portal

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck automatically manage signing.
Select the correct development team and than  choose the provisioning profile.